# How to fix AttributeERROR: 'client' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am Tahsin. I am new in discord.py. when I run my project it shows AttributeERROR: 'client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
How to fix it...

My code
import discord
import asyncio

class MoviesBot:
"""
@token String -> the api token for the Discord API
@movies_provider -> allows searching movies
"""
def **init**(self, token, movies_provider, subtitles_provider):
self.__token = token
self.__movies_provider = movies_provider
self.__subtitles_provider = subtitles_provider
self.__client = discord.Client()

```
    @self.__client.event
    async def on_ready(): await self.handle_ready()

    @self.__client.event
    async def on_message(message): await self.handle_message(message)

@staticmethod
def __get_embed_for_query_result(movie, subs, also=[]):
    # Title and Description
    formatted_title = '{} | {}'.format(movie.title, str(movie.year))
    
    description = movie.description + '\n'
    description += "View on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/{})".format(movie.imdb_id)
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title=formatted_title, description=description)
    
    # Thumbnail
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=movie.thumbnail)

    # Download Links
    for download in movie.downloads:
        download_link = "[Download]({})".format(download['url'])
        embed.add_field(name=download['title'], value=download_link, inline=False)
    
    if subs:
        embed.add_field(name="{} Subtitles".format(subs.language), value="[Download Subs]({})".format(subs.download_url))

    # Footer (Other search options)
    if len(also) > 0:
        other_options = ', '.join(['{} ({})'.format(m.title, m.year) for m in also])
        embed.set_footer(text="Did you mean:\n" + other_options)

    return embed

async def handle_ready(self):
    # Log
    print('Logged in as')
    print(self.__client.user.name)
    print(self.__client.user.id)
    print('------')

@staticmethod
def is_movies_request(message):
    content = message.content
    # Check if keyword matches
    for keyword in ['!movie', '!movies', '!moviebot', '!moviesbot']:
        # If found a match, return True
        if content.startswith(keyword + ' ') and len(content) > len(keyword + ' '):
            return True

    # Return False in case no keyword matched
    return False

@staticmethod
def get_query_from_command(message):
    content = message.content
    # Remove first word
    words = content.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(words[1:])

async def discord_response_for_query(self, query):
    movies = await self.__movies_provider.search_movies(query)
    # If no movies were found
    if len(movies) == 0:
        # present message
        return "Sorry, I didn't find anything.", None
    
    selected_movie = movies[0]
    subtitles = await self.__subtitles_provider.search_subtitles(selected_movie)
    # If only found one movie, return it as single result
    if len(movies) == 1:
        # construct message and present it
        embed = self.__get_embed_for_query_result(selected_movie, subs=subtitles)
        return 'Got It!', embed
    # If found multiple movies, return the best one and other as hints
    elif len(movies) > 1:
        alsoFound = movies[1:]
        # construct message and present it
        embed = self.__get_embed_for_query_result(selected_movie, subs=subtitles, also=alsoFound)
        return'Found some, here is the best one', embed

async def handle_message(self, message):
    if self.is_movies_request(message):
        # Query movies
        query = self.get_query_from_command(message)
        tmp = await self.__client.send_message(message.channel, 'Proccessing...')
        try:
            body, embed = await self.discord_response_for_query(query)
        except:
            print("Error Occured")
            body, embed = "Oops. Something went wrong.", None
        
        await self.__client.edit_message(tmp, body, embed=embed)

def start(self):
    # start the bot
    self.__client.run(self.__token)
```

Comment: how u worte the code is not good way, its the old way so yea

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
await message.channel.send("your message")
```